# xfce keyboard shortcuts not working

Tags: linux, xfce

i am trying to use printscreen button to run the command 'flameshot gui' but for some reason when i press the button it does nothing

it used to work but now it does nothing

when i type 'flameshot gui' into the terminal it does work

[xfce keyboard configuration window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Byeas.png)

sorry if i used this incorrectly its my first time here

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have xfce in Kali 2022.3 and it is somewhat different than you show. There are other Keyboard print shortcuts. Did an update cause a conflict?  Can you use a different keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Kali xfce uses Printscreen (Shift Print) for Screen shot.

You should use a different shortcut key to launch flameshot.gui.

An update likely changed the xfce usage for Printscreen.

[image: Xfce Keyboard Shortcuts]

Comment: i tried to use a different shortcut ("ctrl-alt-t") and did not work, actually i think none of the shortcuts work

Comment: Try reinstalling flamethrower and restart to see if that works. xfce can launch shortcuts via the screen above.

Comment: Also, run the general Linux cleanup.   .....    sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove